# Returning a value from child shell script to a parent script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am having two shell scripts, say script1.sh and script2.sh. I am calling script2.sh from script1.sh. In script2.sh a few evaluations are done and based the results a flag is being set. Now i need to pass the flag to script1.sh based on which it will be decided whether the script1.sh should continue it execution or exit. I am not using functions. and while i export the flag, in script1.sh it is blank. 
 My question now is how do i return the flag from script2.sh ?
 Any help ? Any Ideas? Experiences to share?

Answer (score 3):

You could print the result and capture it in script1:

```
# Script 1
flag="$(./script2.bash)"
```

And:

```
# Script 2
[...]
printf '%s\n' "$flag"
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: I would prefer this solution. Keep in mind that a non-zero exit status typically indicates an error; `script2.bash` may have have several different non-error conditions that result in distinct flag values for `script1.bash`.

Comment: Do you know the solution to return multiple values instead of one?

Comment: I usually return them together as one value, separated by a delimiter that's not present in the variables. Then I use `cut` to separate the return value into multiple values. So, on Script 2 I'd do something like: `printf '%s,%s\n' "$var1" "$var2"` (notice the `,` delimeter inside the `printf` format string). Then on Script 1 I'd do: `single_value="$(./script1.bash)"` followed by `var1="$(echo "$single_value" | cut -f1 -d',')"` and `var2="$(echo $single_value" | cut -f2 -d',')"`. The `-d` specifies the delimiter (in this case, `,`), and the `-f` specifies which field. Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the exit status of script2:

```
if script2.sh ; then
   echo Exited with zero value
else
   echo Exited with non zero
fi
```

Use `exit 0` or `exit 1` in script2 to set the flag.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect you to use the return code from `script2.sh` (se by the statement `exit {value}`)

e.g.

```
./script2.sh
```

`$?` contains the return value from `script2.sh`'s exit statement.

You can't use `export` here. `export` makes the variable available to subsequent subprocesses. It can't be used to communicate a value back to a parent process, since you're modifying a copy of the variable particular to the subprocess.